# insert tags in python string

Tags: python, string, search

I want to highlight search results in python:

```
    search_term = 'highlighted'
    text_string = 'A very long highlighted text'  
    DO THE MAGIC  
    print text_string
```

Output:

```
    A very long <span class="highlight">highlighted</span> text
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
new_string = text_string.replace(
    search_term,
    "<span class='highlighted'>%s</span>" % search_term)
```

As in this context (HTML attributes) it doesn't matter whether you use single quote: `'` or double quote: `"`, I have gone for single as it looks a bit clearer. If you wanted double, you need to escape it: `"<span class=\"highlighted\">"` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
search_term = 'highlighted'
text_string = 'A very long highlighted text'
pre_tag = '<span class="highlight">'
post_tag = '</span>'

# magic, not so magic
text_string = text_string.lower().replace(
    search_term, 
    pre_tag + search_term + post_tag
)
```

This of course if you plan to match *EXACTLY* that same word the user searched.